# Need to fetch only year and month from the date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

Here my value inserted in to the table is like as follows,

```
`2017-01-01`,
`2017-01-02`,
`2017-01-03`,
`2017-01-04`,
`2017-01-05`,
`2017-01-06`.
```

i need to fetch only year and month from that,
for that i used my code like this

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {

    $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
    $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
    $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where(date('Y-m',strtotime($query)), $date);

    return $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_attendance');
}
```

My $date value is `2017-01` and when i gave like this am getting error like this 
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS`numrows`FROM`tbl_attendance`WHERE`tbl_attendance`.`attendance_status`= 1 AND`tbl_attendance`.`user_id`= '1' AND`1970-01`= '2017-01'`

Comment: Please post the error you're getting

Comment: what is date column name in your table ?

Comment: see i had posted it already..

Comment: date_in ? you are saying about ?

Comment: yaa...ofcourse `date_in`

Comment: $date will be in format Y-m ? and your date_in has format Y-m-d right ?

Comment: yes $date is in the format of Y-m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135149/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-user-777).

Comment: Backticks and single inverted commas have different roles in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have error in line

```
$this->db->where(date('Y-m',strtotime($query)), $date);
```

checking value with value,

For now replace your function with this,

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {
    $temp = explode("-",$date);
    $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
    $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
    $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where("YEAR(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[0]);
    $this->db->where("MONTH(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[1]);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_attendance');
}
```

Give it a try, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the date into **Y-m** format then you can use this column as condition

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {

    $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
    $this->db->select('tbl_attendance.*,DATE_FORMAT(tbl_attendance.date_in,"%Y-%m") as date_parse');
    $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
    $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('date_parse',date('Y-m',strtotime($date)));

    return $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_attendance');
}
```

Comment: let me if any error come while running this code.I will fixed it

Comment: column name is date_in not date_parse and its still wont work, because date format is Y-m-d of table field

Comment: Yes I know that date column **tbl_attendance.date_in** what I'm doing I'm formatting the DB date *Y-m-d* into *Y-m* and storing in virtual column *date_parse* and then setting the condition on that column

Comment: try to debug the query which you are getting from the code by using `$this->db->last_query()` and post it here

Comment: mate, I am not OP :D